# choose attribute value while add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

If a product is having attribute, say `color` with it's `Catalog Input Type` as `Multiple Select`, then is Magento provide any way to choose a single attribute value from them while `Add To Cart`? Means if customer wants to choose `red` color from multiple others, then how he can do that?

Any solution for this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly if it's a simple product then you can't select multiple attribute values from the frontend in default magento. Rather you should make custom options of that simple product with input type as Multiple Select.